# Android studio broken after improper computer shutdown

Tags: android, android-studio

I closed my laptop (with android studio running) to hibernate it only to find it fully shutdown later when I arrived home. And now Android Studio completely broke.
I found one java file corrupted which isn't that big of a deal, I can rewrite it. But now I'm getting the "Cannot resolve symbol 'xxx'" for EVERYTHING in a project. I'm getting the error for all imports, even native Android/Java libraries. It does this for all my projects, a simple gradls sync or project rebuild didn't do anything. I'm clueless on what to do to fix this issue.
http://puu.sh/c3eMs/30fcdd99a7.png

Now looking at the screenshot, workspace.xml (of the project which was opened at the time of the shutdown) also got corrupted and unfortunatelly I don't have a backup of it. Not even the github repository have it for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated to get android sudio working again. Reinstalling it would be my very last resort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the screenshot, it looks like you are storing the project in Dropbox. This isn't recommended.

Try this:

After making a backup copy of the project, copy the project to another location on your hard drive. Then clear the cache and Restart Android Studio using File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart. This will give Android Studio a chance to re-index the project. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Why is it not recommended to store your project on dropbox?

Comment: Its not 100% reliable with project caches if used on multiple machines. You may be fine if you only ever access it from one.

Comment: This also worked for me and I am not using Dropbox.   Android Studio got corrupted becase Mac OS X crashed.

Comment: @Longi: I used to save my projects on Dropbox in University to avoid the risk of losing them. That was before I learnt to use Git. If it's a similar story with you, I would definitely suggest you start using Git as early as possible :)

Comment: In some cases it also corrupts the project configuration and can't find any projects anymore. In this case re-importing the project should solve the problem.

Comment: placing the files in another folder worked, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have Solved my problem using steps :

1. File->Invalidate Caches/Restart.
2. Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid having to reinstall Android Studio, try to remove the folders .idea and .gradle inside of your main project folder, and after that make again a File->Restart and invalidate into Android Studio.
In my case that works great :)